# php from text field to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

How can i add multiple text fields in one array?
My code

***HTML***

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags" />
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags" />
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags" />
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags" />
</form>
```

***PHP***

```
$arr = array($_POST['hashtags']);
$arraz = serialize($arr);
$a = addslashes($arraz);
```

***SQL***

```
INSERT INTO table(hashtags) VALUES ($a)
```

And it inserts value only from last text field, how can i insert all text field values?

Comment: Whhat have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have the inputs share a similar name and you want to retrieve them as an array, you have to have the following construction. Notice the [] at the end of the name.

```
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags[]" />
```

Comment: @Cryptonomicon Remove the `array($_POST['hashtags'])` and try again.

Comment: @Cryptonomicon also, make sure you have added the brackets to every instance of `name="hasthags"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to make `hashtags` an array:

```
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags[]" />
...
...
...
<input type="text" class="span6" name="hashtags[]" />
```

Now `$hashtags` is an array in the `$_POST` array:

```
$arraz = serialize($_POST['hashtags']);
$a = addslashes($arraz); //need to use mysqli_real_escape_string() or something
```

Also, that's not a good idea to store them all in one column either serialized or delimited.  Store them individually.

Comment: I added the      `[ ]`  after `hashtag` in input but it still inserts only last value from last input field.

Comment: You need to add it to all inputs with `hashtags` name.

Comment: Look at my edit.  you don't need `$arr = array($_POST['hashtags']);` and that is hosing it.